# Correct way to determine if an object is part of a package hierarchy in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given an object that looks like the following:

```
>>> type(fooInstance)
<class 'myPackage.mySubPackage.myModule.Foo'>
```

What is the best way to test whether some object derives from myPackage? I can do:

```
fooInstance.__module__.split('.')
```

and try to parse the tree this way but is this the correct approach?

Comment: I already answered but I'm wondering what you are looking for here; `myPackage` is the top-level name of the namespace, but is not *necessarily* a package. You can have *empty top-level names* to provide a namespace used by multiple installable projects for example. What exactly is the problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: The basic problem is that I need to determine if I can call an attribute, and if not, run some fallback code. For all of the classes in one package, they overwrite getattr to return None, so I can't use hasattr(obj, 'thingIcareAbout')

So I need to find some other way to special case these objects. (None is an expected result so I can't gate off that)

Comment: Isn't there a base class you can test for then? You can otherwise just use a `obj.__module__.startswith('packagename.')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look up the name in `sys.modules` and see if there is a `__package__` attribute:

```
import sys

package = getattr(sys.modules[fooInstance.__module__], '__package__'), '')
top_level = package.partition('.')[0]
```

The `__package__` attribute should only be set when the module is part of a package.